# In jQuery, if I add a resizable feature to a div, why does it add a weird style to it and how do i fix it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a click function setup to make a div resizable. When I click on the div, the style has white lines and is all spaced out,  I am guessing it might have something to do with the jquery ui css file? How would i go about styling it?

Example: http://www.fissiondesigns.com/simon/

try clicking on one of the boxes on the image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your css thats doing it. when it becomes resizable, jQuery is adding a bunch of div in  `dynamic-pinpoint-area`. All divs the have this rule applied

```
.dynamic-pinpoint-area div {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

you need to be more specific in your css, so it doesnt get applied to generated divs

Answer (score 0):

How about experimenting with jQuery UI's draggable/droppable interactions, as well as sizeable? They're very helpful, and would probably be perfect for this (reducing your code to a minimum as well!)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Comment: I am using both those features in my code, thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: Sorry about that then, I checked the source and didn't spot any references...maybe I should have checked more in detail. Looks like it's a CSS issue then. I'd check the .css file containing the UI classes and go from there.